# Clamp RotateAround is not working on Camera in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, clamp

My code is not working, I am trying to clamp the camera, but it's not working. It's snapping to 45 instantly. How can I clamp the camera?

Here is my Code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

 public class MoveCamera : MonoBehaviour 
 {

     public float sensitivity = 4.0f;        
     private Vector3 mouseOrigin;
     private bool isRotating;

     private float minX = -45.0f;
     private float maxX = 45.0f;

     private float minY = -10.0f;
     private float maxY = 10.0f;

     float rotationY = 0.0f;
     float rotationX = 0.0f;

     void Start()
     {

     }

     void Update () 
     {

         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

             mouseOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
             isRotating = true;
         }

         if (!Input.GetMouseButton (0))
             isRotating = false;

         if (isRotating) {

             Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint (Input.mousePosition - mouseOrigin);
             transform.RotateAround (transform.position, transform.right, -pos.y * sensitivity);
             transform.RotateAround (transform.position, Vector3.up, pos.x * sensitivity);

             rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (transform.localEulerAngles.y, minY, maxY);
             rotationX = Mathf.Clamp (transform.localEulerAngles.x, minX, maxX);
             transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: transform.RotateAround actually rotates the transform, so every update you're rotating, then rotating again with transform.localEulerAngles. What are you wanting the camera to do?

Comment: i want the camera to clamp Y axis to 10 and -10, and X axis to 45 and -45

Comment: if i remove last 3 line, its rotating perfectly as i wanted. but i want to clamp so i added last 3 line but its not clamping.

Comment: Ok, so rather than use transform.RotateAround calculate your angles first, clamp them, then use transform.rotation = whatever. There are various methods you can use in the Quaternion and Vector3 classes to help you with the angles

Comment: Actually, i m new to this, Can you correct the code and post as an answer?  I will accept the answer.  By the way thanks for quick reply :) @Absinthe

Comment: Try transform.Rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos) after your 'Vector3 pos =' line. Delete everything after. Does that work? Happy to code an answer for you if not when I have time.

Comment: @Absinthe No its not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Here is Complete code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveCamera : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public float sensitivity = 4.0f;        
    private Vector3 mouseOrigin;
    private bool isRotating;
    public GameObject cam;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    protected float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max) {

        angle = NormalizeAngle(angle);
        if (angle > 180) {
            angle -= 360;
        } else if (angle < -180) {
            angle += 360;
        }

        min = NormalizeAngle(min);
        if (min > 180) {
            min -= 360;
        } else if (min < -180) {
            min += 360;
        }

        max = NormalizeAngle(max);
        if (max > 180) {
            max -= 360;
        } else if (max < -180) {
            max += 360;
        }

        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }

    protected float NormalizeAngle(float angle) {
        while (angle > 360)
            angle -= 360;
        while (angle < 0)
            angle += 360;
        return angle;
    }


    void Update () 
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

            mouseOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
            isRotating = true;
        }

        if (!Input.GetMouseButton (0))
            isRotating = false;

        if (isRotating) {

            cam.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, ClampAngle(cam.transform.localEulerAngles.y, -45, 45), 0);
            Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint (Input.mousePosition - mouseOrigin);
            transform.RotateAround (transform.position, transform.right, -pos.y * sensitivity);
            transform.RotateAround (transform.position, Vector3.up, pos.x * sensitivity);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of limiting the Y axis rotation, you can adapt it for X too. You didn't state what the limit should be based on so here it's based on the rotation of another object (public Transform target), this could be your player or whatever.

```
public float sensitivity = 16.0f;
public Transform target;

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        //Debug.Log(Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, target.rotation));
        float angle = Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, target.rotation);
        if(angle < 45 || angle > 315)
        {
            Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            transform.RotateAround(pos, Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime * sensitivity);
        }

    }
}
```

If instead you want to limit based on world space just check the rotation of the camera:

```
public float sensitivity = 16.0f;
//public Transform target;

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {

        float angle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        Debug.Log(angle);
        if (angle < 45 || angle > 315)
        {
            Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            transform.RotateAround(pos, Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime * sensitivity);
        }

    }
}
```

Note in both cases the use of Time.deltaTime to ensure the rotation appears to happen at the same speed regardless of the players frame-rate.

If you want to reverse the rotation invert the axis argument of RotateAround:

```
transform.RotateAround(pos, -Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime * sensitivity);
```